# How to stream records by batch with neo4j java driver 4.0.0?

Tags: java, neo4j, driver

Let's say I have a query to a neo4j procedure which should return 100 000 records.
What I would like is a way to get my records by batches of 1000. I don't want to wait for the 100 000 records to be all sent by Neo4j, I would like to control on client side the number of records I receive. I have noticed there is a `CompletionStage<Record> nextAsync()` method in `ResultCursor`, which is doing what I want, but only one record by one. This is not optimal, as it would need too many round trips between the client and neo4j to get all the records. Is there a way to ask for the next N records ?

I am using neo4j java driver 4.0.0 in async mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

In [neo4j 4.0+](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/issues/688#issuecomment-594523327), the `nextAsync()` method internally gets the records in batches for you.

Its implementation returns each record from a queue that is asynchronously replenished, in batches, whenever the queue size falls below a low watermark.

So, the `nextAsync()` method is pretty optimal and should normally get the next record very quickly from the queue.

Comment: if my store procedure should return 100 000 records, and if the nextAsync method is getting the records by batches, how many round trips are done between the client and server ? How can I control the batch size ?

Comment: According to this [discussion](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/issues/688#issuecomment-594523327), your answer is only valid starting Neo4j 4.0. For Neo4j 3.5 and below, all records are pulled in one batch.